# one to one column-value comparison between 2 dataframes - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have 2 dataframe -

```
print(d)
   Year  Salary  Amount  Amount1  Amount2
0  2019    1200      53       53       53
1  2020    3443     455      455      455
2  2021    6777     123      123      123
3  2019    5466     313      313      313
4  2020    4656     545      545      545
5  2021    4565     775      775      775
6  2019    4654     567      567      567
7  2020    7867     657      657      657
8  2021    6766     567      567      567

print(d1)

   Year  Salary  Amount  Amount1  Amount2
0  2019    1200      53       73       63
```

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [
                2019,
                2020,
                2021,
            ] * 3,
    'Salary': [
        1200,
        3443,
        6777,
        5466,
        4656,
        4565,
        4654,
        7867,
        6766
    ],
    'Amount': [
        53,
        455,
        123,
        313,
        545,
        775,
        567,
        657,
        567
    ],
    'Amount1': [
        53,
        455,
        123,
        313,
        545,
        775,
        567,
        657,
        567
    ], 'Amount2': [
        53,
        455,
        123,
        313,
        545,
        775,
        567,
        657,
        567
    ]
})

d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [
        2019
    ],
    'Salary': [
        1200
    ],
    'Amount': [
        53
    ],
    'Amount1': [
        73
    ], 'Amount2': [
        63
    ]
})
```

I want to compare the 'Salary' value of dataframe d1 i.e. 1200 with all the values of 'Salary' in dataframe d and set a count if it is >= or < (a Boolean comparison) - this is to be done for all the columns(amount, amount1, amount2 etc), if the value in any column of d1 is NaN/None, no comparison needs to be done. The name of the columns will always be same so it is basically one to one column comparison.

My approach and thoughts - 
I can get the values of d1 in a list by doing -

```
l = []
for i in range(len(d1.columns.values)):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    else:
        num = d1.iloc[0, i]
        l.append(num)
print(l)

# list comprehension equivalent

lst = [d1.iloc[0, i] for i in range(len(d1.columns.values)) if i != 0]


[1200, 53, 73, 63]
```

and then use iterrows to iterate over all the columns and rows in dataframe d **OR**
I can iterate over d and then perform a similar comparison by looping over d1 - but these would be time consuming for a high dimensional dataframe(d in this case).
What would be the more efficient or pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is the count of times it qualifies the Boolean comparison - for all the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
(df1 >= df2.values).sum()
```

Output:

```
Year       9
Salary     9
Amount     9
Amount1    8
Amount2    8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know what to say - Lesson learnt - sometimes simplest is the best.

Comment: If we have a column say 'Age' only in dataframe d(or df1 as per the solution) above at 0 position - how do we get the values for 'Age' that qualifies (df1.iloc[:,1:] >= df2.values - slicing df1 to not compare 'Age' since it is not present in df2) like it is replied in the solution? Basically, how to get age for which any of the column values(Salary,  Amount,  Amount1,  Amount2) in d1(df1) is > corresponding columns in d(df2).